# error in matrix multiplication in java

Tags: java

I am working on java addition, subtraction and multiplication program.  I have created and completed the program but the output of multiplication is wrong and also i want to check if rows of first matrix equals second or not in matrix multiplication.

```
import java.util.*;

class matrix
{

public static void matrix_oper(int A[][],int B[][],int m, int n, int p, int q)
{

    int[][] C = new int[m][n];
    System.out.println("Matrix A: ");
    for(int i=0 ; i < A.length ; i++)
    {
        System.out.println();
        for(int j=0 ; j < A[i].length ; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(A[i][j]+" ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Matrix B: ");
    for(int i=0 ; i < B.length ; i++)
    { 
        System.out.println();
        for(int j=0 ; j < B[i].length ; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(B[i][j]+" ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Addition Of Matrices: ");
    for(int i=0;i<C.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<C[i].length;j++)
        {
            C[i][j]=A[i][j]+B[i][j];
            System.out.print(C[i][j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Substraction Of Matrices: ");
    for(int i=0;i<C.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<C[i].length;j++)
        {
            C[i][j]=A[i][j]-B[i][j];
            System.out.print(C[i][j]+" ");
        }
    System.out.println();
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Multiplication Of Matrices: ");
    for(int i=0;i<C.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<C[i].length;j++)
        {
            C[i][j]=A[i][j]*B[j][i];
            System.out.print(C[i][j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Number of rows: ");
    int m = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter Number of columns: ");
    int n = input.nextInt();
    int[][] A = new int[m][n];

    System.out.print("Enter Number of rows: ");
    int p = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter Number of columns: ");
    int q = input.nextInt();
    int[][] B = new int[p][q];

    System.out.println("Enter elements for matrix A : ");
    for(int i=0 ; i < A.length ; i++)
        for(int j=0 ; j < A[i].length ; j++)
        {
            A[i][j] = input.nextInt();
        }

    System.out.println("Enter elements for matrix B : ");
    for (int i=0 ; i < B.length ; i++)
        for (int j=0 ; j < B[i].length ; j++)
        {
            B[i][j] = input.nextInt();
        }

    matrix mx=new matrix();
    mx.matrix_oper(A,B,m,n,p,q);
}
}
```

output of this is :

```
Enter Number of rows: 2
Enter Number of columns: 2
Enter elements for matrix A :
1
1
1
1
Enter elements for matrix B :
2
2
2
2
Matrix A:

1 1
1 1

Matrix B:

2 2
2 2

Addition Of Matrices:
3 3
3 3


Substraction Of Matrices:
-1 -1
-1 -1


Multiplication Of Matrices:
2 2
2 2
```

whats error in my matrix multiplication?

Comment: what difference do you get???

Comment: i have posted the output. matrix multiplication is wrong

Comment: What do you expect in the output?

Comment: Take a look at jscience if you need an implementation of matrix operations. It can be useful. http://jscience.org/

Answer (score 10):

try this

```
   for (int i = 0; i < rowsInA; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < columnsInB; j++) {
           for (int k = 0; k < columnsInA; k++) {
               C[i][j] = C[i][j] + A[i][k] * B[k][j];
           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: This gives me error : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 on this line C[i][j] = C[i][j] + A[i][k] * B[k][j];

Comment: check that you have the correct value for rowsInA, columnsInB and columnsInA

Comment: if you have 2d arrays, then rowsInA, columnsInB and columnsInA are all 2

Comment: for matrix multiplication, rows of matrix 1 should be equal to column of matrix 2

Answer (score 1):

Multiplication logic id wrong :
Multiplication of matrix is done by adding multiplications of row elements of A and column elements of B.
Try this one :

```
int[][] C = new int[m][q]; //this is important. the q.
for(int i=0;i<C.length;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<C[i].length;j++) 
    {
        C[i][j]= 0;

          for(k=0;k<n;k++){     //n is column size of A or row size of B.
            C[i][j] += A[i][k]*B[k][j];  //updated
          }
          System.out.print(C[i][j]+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: dis value of j and k will not work for diff row n columns. e.g. for 1st matrix : 2 and 2 and for 2nd matrix 2 and 3